# Efficient retrieval of structural information for nested lists

Tags: r, list, recursion, data-structures, nested-lists

### Actual question

Is there any way I could use or build on top of `rapply()` to derive the same kind of structural information for arbitrarily structured lists that I get via the following function.

Definition:

```
getRawStructure_2 <- function(input) {
  .getRawStructure <- function(x, level = 0) {
    level <- level + 1
    out <- lapply(seq(along = x), function(el) {
      name <- names(x[el])
      value <- x[[el]]
      cls <- class(value)
      .dim <- if (any(cls %in% c("data.frame", "matrix"))) {
        paste(dim(value), collapse = " ")
      } else {
        length(value)
      }  
      out <- data.frame(
        level = level,
        name = if (is.null(name) || name == "") NA else name,
        class = cls,
        dim = .dim,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
      if (any(cls == "list")) {
        deep <- .getRawStructure(x = value, level = level)
        c(list(out), unlist(deep, recursive = FALSE))
      } else {
        list(out)
      }
    })  
  }
  tmp <- do.call("rbind", unlist(.getRawStructure(x = input), recursive = FALSE))
  subs <- tmp$level
  subs_2 <- lapply(1:subs[which.max(subs)], function(ii) {
    out <- subs == ii
    out[out] <- 1
    out
  })
  names(subs_2) <- 1:length(subs_2)
  data.frame(subs_2, tmp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Output:

```
> getRawStructure_2(input)
   X1 X2 X3 level name       class dim
1   1  0  0     1   x1        list   2
2   0  1  0     2  x11        list   2
3   0  0  1     3 x111     numeric   1
4   0  0  1     3 x112     numeric   1
5   0  1  0     2  x12        list   2
6   0  0  1     3 x121     numeric   1
7   0  0  1     3 x122     numeric   1
8   1  0  0     1   x2        list   1
9   0  1  0     2  x21   character   1
10  1  0  0     1   x3        list   1
11  0  1  0     2 <NA>   character   1
12  1  0  0     1   x4   character   1
13  1  0  0     1   x5        list   1
14  0  1  0     2 <NA>     integer   3
15  1  0  0     1 <NA>        list   2
16  0  1  0     2 <NA>        list   2
17  0  0  1     3 <NA>     numeric   1
18  0  0  1     3 <NA>     numeric   1
19  0  1  0     2 <NA>        list   2
20  0  0  1     3 <NA>     numeric   1
21  0  0  1     3 <NA>     numeric   1
22  1  0  0     1 <NA>        list   1
23  0  1  0     2 <NA>     integer   3
24  1  0  0     1 <NA>   character   1
25  1  0  0     1 <NA>   character   1
26  1  0  0     1 <NA>   character   3
27  1  0  0     1 <NA>     numeric   3
28  1  0  0     1 <NA>     logical   1
29  1  0  0     1 <NA> environment   0
30  1  0  0     1 <NA>  data.frame 3 2
```

It's fine for considerably small lists, but it takes some time for larger ones (see example below).

---

### Background

Consider the following list:

```
input <- list(
  x1 = list(x11 = list(x111 = 1, x112 = 1), x12 = list(x121 = 1, x122 = 1)),
  x2 = list(x21 = "x21"),
  x3 = list("x31"),
  x4 = "x4",
  x5 = list(1:3),
  list(list(1, 2), list(3, 4)),
  list(1:3),
  "char 1",
  "char 2",
  letters[1:3],
  c(1,3,5),
  TRUE,
  new.env(),
  data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
)
```

Eventually, I'd like to be able to represent a list in a two-dimensional form like the one returned by [`listr::getStructure()`](https://github.com/Rappster/listr/blob/master/R/getStructure.r):

```
> listr::getStructure(input)
   X1 X2 X3 type           index        oindex        path ppath level name       class dim
1   1 NA NA    1           [[1]]           [1]          x1     1     1   x1        list   2
2   1  1 NA    2      [[1]][[1]]      [[1]][1]      x1/x11   1/1     2  x11        list   2
3   1  1  1    2 [[1]][[1]][[1]] [[1]][[1]][1] x1/x11/x111 1/1/1     3 x111     numeric   1
4   1  1  2    2 [[1]][[1]][[2]] [[1]][[1]][2] x1/x11/x112 1/1/2     3 x112     numeric   1
5   1  2 NA    2      [[1]][[2]]      [[1]][2]      x1/x12   1/2     2  x12        list   2
6   1  2  1    2 [[1]][[2]][[1]] [[1]][[2]][1] x1/x12/x111 1/2/1     3 x121     numeric   1
7   1  2  2    2 [[1]][[2]][[2]] [[1]][[2]][2] x1/x12/x112 1/2/2     3 x122     numeric   1
8   2 NA NA    1           [[2]]           [2]          x2     2     1   x2        list   1
9   2  1 NA    2      [[2]][[1]]      [[2]][1]      x2/x21   2/1     2  x21   character   1
10  3 NA NA    1           [[3]]           [3]          x3     3     1   x3        list   1
11  3  1 NA    2      [[3]][[1]]      [[3]][1]        x3/1   3/1     2 <NA>   character   1
12  4 NA NA    3           [[4]]           [4]          x4     4     1   x4   character   1
13  5 NA NA    1           [[5]]           [5]          x5     5     1   x5        list   1
14  5  1 NA    2      [[5]][[1]]      [[5]][1]        x5/1   5/1     2 <NA>     integer   3
15  6 NA NA    1           [[6]]           [6]           6     6     1 <NA>        list   2
16  6  1 NA    2      [[6]][[1]]      [[6]][1]         6/1   6/1     2 <NA>        list   2
17  6  1  1    2 [[6]][[1]][[1]] [[6]][[1]][1]       6/1/1 6/1/1     3 <NA>     numeric   1
18  6  1  2    2 [[6]][[1]][[2]] [[6]][[1]][2]       6/1/2 6/1/2     3 <NA>     numeric   1
19  6  2 NA    2      [[6]][[2]]      [[6]][2]         6/2   6/2     2 <NA>        list   2
20  6  2  1    2 [[6]][[2]][[1]] [[6]][[2]][1]       6/2/1 6/2/1     3 <NA>     numeric   1
21  6  2  2    2 [[6]][[2]][[2]] [[6]][[2]][2]       6/2/2 6/2/2     3 <NA>     numeric   1
22  7 NA NA    1           [[7]]           [7]           7     7     1 <NA>        list   1
23  7  1 NA    2      [[7]][[1]]      [[7]][1]         7/1   7/1     2 <NA>     integer   3
24  8 NA NA    3           [[8]]           [8]           8     8     1 <NA>   character   1
25  9 NA NA    3           [[9]]           [9]           9     9     1 <NA>   character   1
26 10 NA NA    3          [[10]]          [10]          10    10     1 <NA>   character   3
27 11 NA NA    3          [[11]]          [11]          11    11     1 <NA>     numeric   3
28 12 NA NA    3          [[12]]          [12]          12    12     1 <NA>     logical   1
29 13 NA NA    3          [[13]]          [13]          13    13     1 <NA> environment   0
30 14 NA NA    3          [[14]]          [14]          14    14     1 <NA>  data.frame 3 2
```

In order to do so, I've experimented with a couple of different approaches. The speed of `rapply()` seems really intriguing (see benchmarks below), but AFAICT I can't really use it for my purposes as `f` is exclusively applied to leaf/bottom values, thus I'm "loosing any "in-between" information about branches or the list structure itself, right?.

Should there be any way to nevertheless use `rapply()` - or a tweaked version - somehow, I'd really appreciate any pointer.

Definitions:

```
require("stringr")
getRawStructure_1 <- function(input) {
  struc <- capture.output(str(input, list.len = length(input)))
  struc <- unlist(strsplit(struc, split = "\n"))
  tops <- str_count(struc, "\\s\\$\\s")
  subs <- str_count(struc, "((\\.\\.)(\\s|\\$))")

  ## Clean //
  idx_out <- which(tops == 0 & subs == 0)
  if (length(idx_out)) {
    tops <- tops[-idx_out]
    subs <- subs[-idx_out]
    struc <- struc[-idx_out]
  }

  ## Types //
  types <- gsub(".*\\$(\\s*:|\\s*\\w+:)", "", struc)
  types <- gsub("(?<=\\w)\\s.*|\\:.*", "", types, perl = TRUE)
  types <- tolower(gsub("\\s|<|'", "", types))

  ## Names //
  idx_names <- str_detect(struc, "\\$\\s\\w+.*:\\s")
  nms <- if (length(idx_names)) {
    gsub("\\$\\s", "", str_extract(struc, "\\$\\s\\w+"))
  } else {
    NA
  }

  ## Levels //
  subs_2 <- lapply(0:subs[which.max(subs)], function(ii) {
    out <- subs == ii
    out[out] <- 1
    out
  })
  names(subs_2) <- 1:length(subs_2)
  data.frame(
    subs_2, 
    name = nms, 
    class = types, 
    str = struc, 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )  
}

getRawStructure_3 <- function(input) {
  .getRawStructure <- function(x) {
    list(level = length(x), class = class(x))
  }
  rapply(input, .getRawStructure, how = "list")
}

getRawStructure_1(input)
getRawStructure_2(input)
getRawStructure_3(input)
```

Benchmarks:

```
require("microbenchmark")
res <- microbenchmark(
  "0.1" = str(input, list.len = length(input)),
  "0.2" = capture.output(str(input, list.len = length(input))),
  "1" = getRawStructure_1(input),
  "2" = getRawStructure_2(input),
  "3" = getRawStructure_3(input),
  unit = "ms"
)

> res
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq       mean   median        uq       max neval
  0.1 22.526810 24.431485 25.3388115 25.04150 26.160263 29.466200   100
  0.2 15.678034 17.549247 17.9725577 17.79237 18.328352 22.353281   100
    1 17.977740 20.286033 21.1265184 20.59993 21.396797 35.075989   100
    2 17.647265 19.622121 20.2261508 20.03640 20.860219 25.066969   100
    3  0.076993  0.092095  0.1055568  0.09861  0.112527  0.251706   100
```

Larger lists:

```
scope <- 1000
input <- lapply(1:scope, function(ii) {
  list(name = paste(sample(letters, 4), collapse = ""), value = Sys.time())
})
head(input)

res <- microbenchmark(
  "0.1" = str(input, list.len = length(input)),
  "0.2" = capture.output(str(input, list.len = length(input))),
  "1" = getRawStructure_1(input),
  "2" = getRawStructure_2(input),
  "3" = getRawStructure_3(input),
  unit = "ms",
  times = 3
)

> res
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
  0.1 2449.80358 2481.302677 2494.523763 2512.801773 2516.883854 2520.965936     3
  0.2 1591.30210 1662.759397 1696.973466 1734.216693 1749.809148 1765.401602     3
    1 1600.41742 1647.050567 1669.736494 1693.683716 1704.396033 1715.108349     3
    2 2051.56185 2052.655737 2077.485806 2053.749622 2090.447782 2127.145943     3
    3    7.98708    8.559489    8.765691    9.131898    9.154996    9.178094     3
```